# c#: start appium server using process start lean to Win32Exception

Tags: c#, process, appium

So I have this function that start `process`:

```
public class ProcessHandler
{
    private static Process process;
    private static ListenerHandler listenerHandler = new ListenerHandler();

    public static void Start(string fileName, string arguments)
    {
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        if (arguments != "")
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }

    private static void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }

    private static void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Todo.
    }

    public static void Kill()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!process.HasExited)
                process.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }          
    }
}
```

And want to use it in order to start `appium` server.
In my `machine` what I want to start `appium` server I just open `cmd` windows type `appium` and the server started.

So I try to use it this way with this class example:

```
ProcessHandler.Start("appium", "");
```

And received this error (at process.Start()):

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file
> specified'

I have check my function with another example:

```
ProcessHandler.Start("notepad", @"C:\log.txt");
```

And this works fine.